# Beginner code for MadLibs game

Tags: python, beginner, regex

I am working through Automate the Boring Stuff. How can I make this code cleaner/better?

```
#madlibs.py : ABS Chapter 8 Project
#Make mad libs using madlibtemplate.txt file that will prompt user for parts of speech
#Will return new file with replacements called madlib.txt

import re, os

#Create template.txt file if doesn't exist

print("Let's play MadLibs! \n Note: Your current working directory is ", os.getcwd())
if os.path.exists('madlibtemplate.txt') == False:
    print("No template file found. Using default 'madlibtemplate.txt'")
    template = open('madlibtemplate.txt', 'w+')
    template.write("""The ADJECTIVE girl walked to the NOUN and then VERB.
    A nearby NOUN was upset by this.""")
else:
    print("Using your 'madlibtemplate.txt' file:")
    template = open('madlibtemplate.txt', 'r')

#Extract text from template file & turn into list of words

template.seek(0) #reset pointer to beginning of file
text = (template.read()).lower() #make lowercase to match parts of speech

wordregex = re.compile(r'\w+|\s|\S')
words = re.findall(wordregex, text)

#Find and replace parts of speech

for i, word in enumerate(words):
    for part_of_speech in ['adjective', 'noun', 'adverb', 'verb', 'interjection']:
        if word == part_of_speech:
            print('Enter a(n) %s ' % part_of_speech)
            words[i] = input()

madlib_text_unformatted = ''.join(words)

#Capitalize first letter in each sentence (Function found on stackoverflow)

def sentence_case(text):
    # Split into sentences. Therefore, find all text that ends
    # with punctuation followed by white space or end of string.
    sentences = re.findall('[^.!?]+[.!?](?:\s|\Z)', text)

    # Capitalize the first letter of each sentence
    sentences = [x[0].upper() + x[1:] for x in sentences]

    # Combine sentences
    return ''.join(sentences)

madlib_text = sentence_case(madlib_text_unformatted)

#Print result and save to a new file

print('Here we go... \n')
print(madlib_text)

madlib = open('madlib.txt', 'w')
madlib.write(madlib_text)
madlib.close()
template.close()

print("\n This has been saved to file 'madlib.txt'")
```

Answer (score 4):

- You could use a bit less comments, most of the code is self-explnatory
- You could also use a bit more split of the code into functions, e.g. a function to create a default file
- This is a full script, so it's nice to have the `if __name__ == "__main__":` condition to call the main function
- If you use the `"""` to have a multi-line string, whatever you put will be there, including newlines and tabs. You probably want to split the string by using `"` on separate lines (see later).
- Also, if you concatenate that way, you're losing the `\n`, it's better to use `format`

Revised code:

```
#madlibs.py : ABS Chapter 8 Project
#Make mad libs using madlibtemplate.txt file that will prompt user for parts of speech
#Will return new file with replacements called madlib.txt

import re, os

def generate_default_template():
    with open('madlibtemplate.txt', 'w+') as template:
        template.write("The ADJECTIVE girl walked to the NOUN and then VERB. "
                        "A nearby NOUN was upset by this.")

def capitalize_sentences(text):
    sentences = re.findall('[^.!?]+[.!?](?:\s|\Z)', text)
    capitalized_sentences = [sentence.capitalize() for sentence in sentences]
    return ''.join(capitalized_sentences)


def main():
    print("Let's play MadLibs!\nNote: Your current working directory is {0}".format(os.getcwd()))
    if not os.path.exists('madlibtemplate.txt'):
        print("No template file found. Using default 'madlibtemplate.txt'")
        generate_default_template()
    else:
        print("Using your 'madlibtemplate.txt' file:")

    with open('madlibtemplate.txt', 'r') as template:
        template.seek(0)
        text = (template.read()).lower()

    wordregex = re.compile(r'\w+|\s|\S')
    words = re.findall(wordregex, text)

    for i, word in enumerate(words):
        if word in {'adjective', 'noun', 'adverb', 'verb', 'interjection'}:
            print('Enter a(n) %s ' % word)
            words[i] = input()

    madlib_text_unformatted = ''.join(words)
    madlib_text = capitalize_sentences(madlib_text_unformatted)

    print('Here we go... \n')
    print(madlib_text)

    with open('madlib.txt', 'w') as madlib:
        madlib.write(madlib_text)

    print("\nThis has been saved to file 'madlib.txt'")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- If you want to capitalize a word, there's the... well, `capitalize` function for that.
- When opening files it's nice to use the `with` keyword, so they'll be closed automatically.
- You don't need to do a loop when checking the parts of speech, just use the `in` operator.